# Spark load Z compressed file using Scala on Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compression, azure-databricks

Is there a way to read a `.Z` (capital) file extension with `Spark` directly?

I know `Scala` with `spark` can read `gzip` files `(.gz)` directly, but when I try to load a compressed `Z` file `(.Z)` into a `Dataframe` it doesn’t work.

Comment: theoretically it should be supported by underlying Hadoop implementation

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you can’t read a file `.Z` is because `Spark` try to match the file extension with **registered compression codecs** and no codec handlers the extension `.Z` !!

All you had to do is to extend `GzipCodec` and override the `getDefaultExtension` method.

As an example:

Here is our **ZgzipCodec.scala**

```scala
package codecs
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
class ZgzipCodec extends GzipCodec{
    override def getDefaultExtension(): String = ".Z"

}
```

```scala
package tests

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ReadingGzipFromZExtension{
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("ReadingGzipFromZExtension")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id", "ReadingGzipFromZExtension")  // To silence Metrics warning
    .config("spark.hadoop.io.compression.codecs", "codecs.ZgzipCodec") // Custom Codec that process .Z extensions as a common Gzip format
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val data = spark.read.csv("/path/file.Z")
    data.show()

    sc.stop()
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

You could follow this link for further details:
[Reading compressed data with Spark using unknown file extensions](https://arjon.es/2015/reading-compressed-data-with-spark-using-unknown-file-extensions/)